# IceCast Currently playing not updating when % sign being used

Tags: icecast

For some reason, when the % sign is used within my text file, the icecast 'currently playing' field does not get updated.. when the % sign is not there it works fine. i've seen icecast radio streams where the % sign is working. do I need to do something special to include it?

Thanks

Comment: Please include more information. What source client are you using? What are you doing with the 'text file'?

Comment: I am using Icecast 2.4.4 with butt 0.1.18. I have a .txt file which gets updated with the song name, radio slogans etc depending on what's playing within the radio software. When the % sign is included in the txt file, that particular line which has the % sign does not upload to my icecast currently playing field.

Comment: you really should put that information in the question. As it's BUTT that consumes the file, not Icecast! It's likely a bug in BUTT.

Comment: Okay thanks, will contact the developer!